# Método Getter en Typescript : ¿Cómo funciona?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formularios, get

Buenos días estoy realizando un formulario reactivo con Angular 10 y para hacer una de las validaciones me recomendaron utilizar el metodo getter ya que realicé un método con condicionales y no me funcionó

El getter es el siguiente: este tiene como fin validar el campo del nombre y me devuelve un booleano el caso de que sea true le agregaré la clase invalida al campo. [Con this.forma hago mención a la propiedad de tipo formGroup]

```
get validarnombre() {
return this.forma.get('nombre')?.invalid && this.forma.get('nombre')?.touched;}
```

Luego tengo otra duda: no estoy entendiendo porqué en lugar de acceder a la propiedad nombre (que se encuentra dentro de mi objecto forma) NO me deja acceder de la siguiente manera:

```
  this.forma["nombre"]
```

pero me SI me deja acceder utilizando .get :

```
this.forma.get('nombre')
```

Otra duda también seria porque no me funcionó el método que creé para validar, entiendo que seria hasta mejor que el getter, el método es el siguiente:

```
validarnombre(): boolean {
if (this.forma.get('nombre')?.invalid && this.forma.get('nombre')?.touched) {
  return false;
}else{
  return true ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre tu duda de la obtención de la propiedad.

Esto se debe a que tu formulario no es un arreglo, es un objeto **AbstractControl**, si imprimes tu formulario en consola, veras que es un objeto con sus distintas propiedades, el método *get* lo encontraras en `formulario.__proto__.__proto__.get`

```js
__proto__:
    clearAsyncValidators: ƒ ()
    clearValidators: ƒ ()
    disable: ƒ (opts)
    enable: ƒ (opts)
    get: ƒ (path)
        arguments: (...)
        caller: (...)
        length: 1
        name: ""
        prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
        __proto__: ƒ ()
        [[FunctionLocation]]: forms.umd.js? [sm]:3376
        [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
```

En la línea 3376 de forms.umd.js podrás checar el método *get*:

```js
 /**
         * Retrieves a child control given the control's name or path.
         *
         * @param path A dot-delimited string or array of string/number values that define the path to the
         * control.
         *
         * @usageNotes
         * ### Retrieve a nested control
         *
         * For example, to get a `name` control nested within a `person` sub-group:
         *
         * * `this.form.get('person.name');`
         *
         * -OR-
         *
         * * `this.form.get(['person', 'name']);`
         */
        AbstractControl.prototype.get = function (path) {
            return _find(this, path, '.');
        };
```

Sobre tu segunda duda, si usas una función como la siguiente:

```
validarnombre(): boolean {
if (this.forma.get('nombre')?.invalid && this.forma.get('nombre')?.touched) {
  return false;
}else{
  return true ;
}
```

Este código solo se ejecutara una vez para validar tu formulario, en cambio usando la palabra reservada *get* en tu función, estará obteniendo el valor de manera constante.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias oscar, una sola unica se podria obtener la propiedad de esta forma:  this.forma.nombre en lugar de : this.forma.get('nombre')

Comment: @RenzoTorrente, no puedes utilizar `this.forma.nombre` dado que la propiedad *nombre* no se encuentra en `this.forma`  por que es un objeto **FormGroup**. Una alternativa para acceder al control *nombre* sería `this.forma.controls.nombre` , donde `this.forma.controls` es un objeto con las propiedades de tu formulario.

Comment: Genial, pero entonces cuando debo aplicar el metodo .get para obtener el valor de una propiedad? y cual seria la logica de este ejemplo:   this.forma.get('nombre')

Comment: @RenzoTorrente, depende de cada quien, en lo personal te recomendaría usar el método `.get` cuando quieras acceder a una propiedad anidada, es decir un formulario mas complejo.